# Creating new nodes in a trie data structure in C

Tags: c, trie

I'm trying to implement a trie data structure in `C` and having trouble figuring out how to dynamically name new nodes that are added to the dictionary. See the last few lines of my `add` method where I try to create a new node and try to point to it.

```
bool add(char *word, node tree)
{
    // Creates a variable to store the current char in the string
    char currChar = word[0];
    // Converts the current char to an index #
    int currCharIndex = ((int) toupper(currChar)) - 65;

    // Checks if we've reached the end of the word
    if (currChar == '\0')
    {
        // Sets current node word to true
        tree.word = true;
    }
    // Checks if next letter in word is not NULL
    else if (tree.children[currCharIndex] != NULL)
    {
        // Follows the pointer
        return add(&word[1], *tree.children[currCharIndex],);
    }
    else
    {
        //Creates a new node
        node; // TODO: name node
        // Points the current node to the new node
        tree.children[currCharIndex] = &// TODO: new node name
        return add(&word[1], *tree.children[currCharIndex]);
    }
}
```

Here is how I define `node`:

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool word;
    struct node *children[26];
}
node;

bool search(char *word, node tree);
bool add(char *word, node tree);

int main(void)
{
    node dictionary;
}
```

Comment: Please show how `node` is defined, so that SO can help you. The way `node` passed to `add` (pass by value) does not look right. You may need to pass pointer to `node`. Similarly, you cannot add a local variable `node <whatever-name>` to `add` as it will go out of scope. You need to allocate memory using `malloc` and then add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the prototype of `add` that you have, you pass `tree` by value and so whatever changes done to `tree` inside `add` will get lost after the function returns. You first need to change prototype of `add` to take pointer as below.

```
bool add(char *word, node * tree)
```

Then you can allocate memory to add the node as below

```
...
else
{
    //Creates a new node
    node * newnode;
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    //TODO Initialize newnode i.e. set all children to NULL.
    tree->children[currCharIndex] = newnode;
    return add(&word[1], tree->children[currCharIndex]);
}
```

Also fix other parts of the code to pass pointer instead of value.

```
...
else if (tree->children[currCharIndex] != NULL)
{
    return add(&word[1], tree->children[currCharIndex]);
}
```